# fopen() for FTP Explicit SSL/TLS

Tags: php, ftp, ftps, ftpes

How can I use `fopen("ftp://$user:$pass@$domain/test.php", "wb");` for FTP Explicit SSL/TLS ?

Something like `fopen("ftpes://$user:$pass@$domain/test.php", "wb");`.

`ftpes://` is not listed in [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)

From Filezilla Client, I can confirm that ftpes://$domain is right and even the user credentials are correct.

Basically I want to write the contents directly through `fwrite()`, the same code works for ftp and ftps but not ftpes.

Let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You want [ftp_ssl_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php), but keep in mind that if you're on Windows you need to compile your own php binary and statically link the OpenSSL and ftp modules.